# JSON.stringify gets very slow when it stringify a string to json

Tags: node.js

I just get started learning some JavaScript and I encountered a strange problem when I use JSON.stringify to convert a string into json format. It got very slow and evantually produced a wrong result(not <"what ever in the string">). At the point where it happens, the source of the string is actually a TCP connection(to a java program). Here is the code I used.

```
var http = require("http"); 
http.createServer(function (request, response) {
    response.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'application/json'});

    var net = require('net');
    var client = new net.Socket();

    client.connect(3344,'192.168.1.4',function(){
        ......
    }

    client.on('data', function(result){
        ......
        response.write(JSON.stringify(result));
        ......
        response.end();
    });

    client.on('error', function(ex) {
        var error = "error code: "+ex.code;
        response.write(JSON.stringify(error));
        response.end();
    }
});
```

(Result is a plain text that has nothing to do with JSON)
when it executed to "response.write(JSON.stringify(result));", it almost stopped there for a minute and gave me a wrong result. However, the "response.write(JSON.stringify(error));" down below works complete fine. So I change the code a little bit to:

```
var http = require("http"); 
http.createServer(function (request, response) {
    response.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'application/json'});

    var net = require('net');
    var client = new net.Socket();

    client.connect(3344,'192.168.1.4',function(){
        ......
    }

    client.on('data', function(result){
        ......
        var result2 = result+' ';
        response.write(JSON.stringify(result2));
        ......
        response.end();
    });

    client.on('error', function(ex) {
        var error = "error code: "+ex.code;
        response.write(JSON.stringify(error));
        response.end();
    }
});
```

Then there is no problem at all.

I suppose there are some problem with the character encoding? Does anyone know why it behaves like this?

Comment: Why are you stringifying a JSON data response and not simply responding with well-formed JSON data? Your header sets the `content-type` to JSON, yet you're attempting to send back a string.

Comment: I just started doing this and I didn't realize the difference between sending stringified JSON string and responding with JSON. Could you tell me how to send back a well-formed JSON data?

Comment: Just send back `result`. No need to call any `JSON` methods on it.

Comment: do you mean "response.write(result)"? That would just send what's in the result string instead of a json format response. I may add more infomation to send back in the future, so I would like to send in json.

Comment: Not sure the format of `result`. If `result` is already a string, then you'll need to do `JSON.parse(result)`. If `result` is just an object literal, then you can just do `response.write(result)`.

Comment: The result is just a plain text(has nothing to do with JSON), and I want to make it into a JSON that include this string. JSON.parse seems would convert string of JSON text into an object, which is completely the opposite to what I want to do.

Comment: @MingchenZhang Just add the sample `result` to the question and how you want to send the response for that `result`.

Answer (score 1):

```
var http = require("http"); 
http.createServer(function (request, response) {
    response.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'application/json'});

    var net = require('net');
    var client = new net.Socket();

    client.connect(3344,'192.168.1.4',function(){
        ......
    }

    client.on('data', function(result){
        ......
        response.write(result);
        //response.write({"data":result});
        ......
        response.end();
    });

    client.on('error', function(ex) {
        var error = "error code: "+ex.code;
        response.write(error);
        //response.write({"error code":ex.code});
        response.end();
    }
});
```